# Dirty JSON objects not in array - how can I parse this?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm currently trying to parse the following JSON output.
These JSON objects are stored in one big string and not in a JSON array. As such it is not valid JSON.

```
{"output": "te\ns\nt"}
{"output": "test"}
```

*This string also contains multiple new lines. So splitting on new lines is not an option.*

Nevertheless is there any way of parsing this invalid JSON that it results in a valid array of JSON objects?

Comment: Absolutely, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Are we working with a string of json objects?

Comment: Yes we are :) In fact it is the dirty output of a command line tool.

Comment: @mhodges Not really, I'm trying to parse a string full of JSON objects (but not stored in an array).

Comment: @WouterBloeyaert Just saw that. I might update your post to be more clear. "These JSON objects are stored in one big [blob --> string]"

Comment: @mhodges Updated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your object-list (let's call it that) contains valid objects you can first make an array from each line and then go through that array and parse the JSON:

```js
let data = `{"output": "test"}

{"output": "test"}`; //template string to make the newlines work flawless...

//         first split on newline               filter out ""     map to the parsed JSON
data = data.replace(/}\n*/g, "}**").split("**")  .filter(Boolean)  .map(JSON.parse);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Indeed, but this will break if multiple \n newlines are present in the string. Which in fact is the case in the output produced by the command line tool I'm using.

Comment: @WouterBloeyaert You can `.filter()` out empty lines. `.split().filter(Boolean).map(...)`

Comment: thanks @mhodges! Now, the only thing I can't get to work is how to handle literal and unescaped `\n`s in the objects... any idea on that?

Comment: For example if your data is ```data = `{"output": "test"}\n{"output": "te\nst"}`;```

Comment: @WouterBloeyaert See above comment to Luca

Comment: @mhodges That seems to work, let me test on command output :)

Comment: @WouterBloeyaert Actually, try this instead `/}\n*/g`

Comment: Yes, It also removes the last curly brace on each element

Comment: @Luca It seems the Regex cuts of the last '''}'''. Can you confirm?

Comment: @luca Ah ok, you also noticed it :)

Comment: Do you have data that looks like this (`{"output": "te\nst"}`)? (not escaped)?

Comment: @WouterBloeyaert `.replace(/}\n*/g, "}**").split("**").map(...)` How about that? Seems to work for me

Comment: Yes seems to work but adds a single item without content in the end ;)

Comment: Also works for me. Only problem would seem to be the data containing `**`... The element in the end is elmiminated by the filter(Boolean)

Comment: @WouterBloeyaert Forgot `.filter(Boolean)`, sorry. The full line would be: `.replace(/}\n*/g, "}**").split("**").filter(Boolean).map(...)`

Comment: Ok let's try :)

Comment: @Luca Yeah, and you can make that delimeter whatever you want - even something crazy like `"!@#$%*%@"` or `"mysuperlonganddefinitelyuniquedelimiter"`

Comment: Thanks for your input :) @mhodges Feel to update your description

Comment: @WouterBloeyaert the edit would've made the code not work anymore. The spacing is just to indicate what part does what ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's something dirty that might work.

```
let string = `{"output": "te\ns\nt"}
{"output": "test"}`

let json = JSON.parse(`[${string.replace(/}[\s]*\{/g, '}, {').replace(/\n/g, '\\n')}]`)

console.log(json) // [ { output: 'te\ns\nt' }, { output: 'test' } ]
```

Not pretty and quite fragile, but quick.